# Apache - Rewrite url without loop

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Well I say what's said in the title again, I can't find a way to rewrite all my urls without getting a loop. 
I've tried many options but I can't find about one way which avoid a redirection loop:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)  http://example.com/example/index.php$1  [R,L]                                                                                                                         
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /var/www/example/index.php$1 [R]                                                                                                                              
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example/index.php$1 [R]  
RewriteRule ^$ /example/ [L]
```

And below is my directory apache-conf

```
<Directory /var/www/example>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I understand why it loops though I can't imagine (either find!) the good rule to do what I want.

**EDIT**

Basically I'm redirecting example.fr hosted at OVH to an IP virtual machine. Does this could get involved in my issue ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
  RewriteRule (.*) /example/index.php/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect anything that is outside /example/ to /example/index.php adding the original path in the end

EDIT:
So, if you want everything to be redirected to `/project_name/index.php` instead, you need to swap the word "*example*" both in `RewriteCond` and in `RewriteRule` lines with your project name...

PS:
The `RewriteCond` line here is needed to ensure the rewriting does not loop (hence the url stayed `/example/contact` when you tried this).

Comment: With this I still get the "It Works!" page from apache. I've restarted apache /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: 1. Where have you put this? 2. What is the value of `AllowOverride` directive?

Comment: in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. I had AllowOverride None from de default site enabled file conf. I let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Still the same. I've "It works!" page on ``/`` and if I go to ``example.fr/example`` then I access the home page. But as soon as I want to go for instance to example.fr/example/contact I get 404

Comment: Does it stay on `/example.fr/example/contact` URI or does the url change when you get 404? P.S. where would you *want* `example.fr/example/contact` to be redirected exactly? To `/example/index.php/example.fr/example/contact` or somewhere else?

Comment: No it stays at ``http://domain.fr/example/contact``. Bassicaly i would like that any kind of string appended to ``http://domain.fr/`` get appended to ``http://domain.fr/project_name/``. Might go to chat if I'm not clear enough ? Cheers

Comment: The fact that it stays inside `/example/contact` is the exact result of the rule - `RewriteCond` above makes sure the URI's inside `/example/` are not rewritten, and the rule after it makes **everything outside of it** rewrite into `/example/index.php/$1` (i believed that was what you asked for while writing the answer) :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12803/discussion-between-renard-and-poncha)

Answer (score 1):

This rule should not cause a loop

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)  http://example.com/example/index.php$1  [R,L]
```

This rule will not do anything at all

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /var/www/example/index.php$1 [R]
```

For this rule you should add a RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example/index.php$1 [R]
```

This is fine

```
RewriteRule ^$ /example/ [L]
```